# Iterating through Angular Reactive Form

Tags: angular

I have an Angular reactive form which is dynamically created.

I have a function which is called when the 'rate' or 'quantity' fields changes.  I'd like to iterate through the form and multiply the rate and quantity for each item and add them all together to get a grand total.

How do I do that? I've tried using .forEach, but that doesn't seem to work on FormArrays

This the json structure of my form:

```
{
  "quoteDate": "2019-01-11T11:00:00",
  "quoteItems": [
    {
      "description": "",
      "quoteLineItems": [
        {
          "rate": 8,
          "quantity": 78,
        },
        {
          "rate": 2,
          "quantity": 32,
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "",
      "quoteLineItems": [
        {
          "rate": 24,
          "quantity": 5,
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "",
      "quoteLineItems": [
        {
          "rate": 1,
          "quantity": 2145,
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is how I'm creating my form:

```
createForm() {
    this.quoteForm = this.fb.group({
      quoteDate: [this.quote.quoteDate, Validators.required],
      quoteItems: this.fb.array([])
    });
    this.addQuoteV2Item();
}

get quoteItems() {
  return this.quoteForm.get('quoteItems') as FormArray;
}

quoteLineItems(index) {
  return (this.quoteForm.get('quoteItems') as FormArray).at(index).get('quoteLineItems') as FormArray

}

addQuoteItem() {
  this.quoteItems.push(this.fb.group({
    description: '',
    quoteLineItems: this.fb.array([])
  }));
}

addQuoteLineItem(index, description) {
  this.quoteLineItems(index).push(
    this.fb.group({
      rate: '',
      quantity: '',
      total: 0
    })

  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving:

```
updateTotal() {
  var subtotal = 0;
  var numberOfQuoteItems = (this.quoteForm.get('quoteItems') as FormArray).length;

  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfQuoteItems; i++) {
      var numberOfQuoteLineItems = ((this.quoteForm.get('quoteItems') as FormArray).at(i).get('quoteLineItems') as FormArray).length;
      for (let j = 0; j < numberOfQuoteLineItems; j++) {
        var currentLineItem = ((this.quoteForm.get('quoteItems') as FormArray).at(i).get('quoteLineItems') as FormArray).at(j);
        subtotal = subtotal + currentLineItem.value.rate * currentLineItem.value.quantity;
      }
  }
  this.subtotal = subtotal;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the method `valueChanges` which returns an observable, so you will need to subscribe to it.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.quoteForm.valueChanges.subscribe(inputField => {
    if (inputField.rate) {
      // Do something with the rate value
    } else if (inputField.quantity) {
      // Do something with the quantity value
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: How do I do that to get the nested quantity and rate fields ?

Comment: @RobbieMills if I am not mistaking, `this.quoteForm.quoteDate.quoteItems[0]quoteLineItems[0]rate` returns `8`. If you want the dynamic values, you will need to loop through each array (in my case I have just used `[0]` for the first value). Now you can use `for` or `forEach` to do that.

Comment: Ok so the problem is that I cannot use forEach on a FormArray (not a function error), that's what I need to do